# Listagem dados Gráfico Android

Tags: android, delphi

Bom dia,

Tenho um aplicativo a onde consigo visualizar os dados do cliente em forma de listagem e gráfico, queria uma sugestão de vocês qual componente eu poderia usar no mobile para visualizar os dados em forma de gráfico.

Desde já agradeço atenção de vocês!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem o [TeeChart](https://www.steema.com/product/vcl) da Steema que é muito bom, porem não é uma ferramenta livre. Apesar de que algumas de suas funcionalidades já vem disponíveis com a instalação de algumas versões do Delphi.

Comment: Estive dando uma olhada, funciona da mesma forma que na VCL, achei que não tinha para mobile. valeu!